# Python: Check if string is in list of characters in the correct order

Tags: python, string, list

I want to check if eg. if the string `ABC` is in the list `["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"]`, which should return True, but should not return True on `["B", "C", "A"]`, because it isn't in the order of `ABC`
For what I am doing it is only important to know if it is in the List or not and the remaining characters can be ignored.
If a character that is in the word, comes up two or more times in a row, the program should read them as just one instance of that letter, except of course if the double letter is part of the word.
So something like `"ABC" in ["A", "B", "B", "C"]` should still return `True`.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Could you post your attempts?

Comment: `"ABC" in ["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"] and not "ABC" in  ["B", "C", "A"]`?

Comment: `"ABC" in ["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"]` returns False, shouldn't it return True?

Comment: You mean you want to check if `"A"` and `"B"` and `"C"` are all individually in the list in that order, right?

Comment: What should the result be if your list is `["A", "B", "B", "C"]`?

Comment: It should still be True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = ["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"]
s = 'ABC'

i = iter(lst)
if all(any(v == ch for v in i) for ch in s):
    print('FOUND')
else:
    print('NOT FOUND')
```

Prints:

```
FOUND
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution (`lst1` and `lst2` are your two lists):

```
f = lambda lst: ''.join(c for c in lst if c in set('ABC'))
if 'ABC' in f(lst1):
    ...
```

For example:

```
>>> lst1 = ["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"]
>>> lst2 = ["B", "C", "A"]
>>> 'ABC' in f(lst1)
True
>>> 'ABC' in f(lst2)
False
>>> 'ABC' in f(lst1) and 'ABC' not in f(lst2)
True
```

**EDIT**
Here is another solution that keeps into account a special case you mentioned later:

```
i = iter(lst)
if all(next((x for x in i if x == c), None) is not None for c in 'ABC'):
    ...
```

Comment: What about `'ABC' in f(['A', 'B', 'B', C'])`?

Comment: @khelwood In this case `False` is returned, but I am not sure what is the desired behaviour, are you? This should be a question for the OP :)

Comment: should return True

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to reduce it to just the letters you care about and then check the order. It's not the most efficient solution but it's simplistic to write:

```py
targetString = "ABC"
testArray = ["F", "A", "g", "B", "C"]

def testString(strg, lst):
    letters = set(strg)
    filtered = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in letters, lst))
    return filtered == strg

testString(targetString, testArray)
```

Comment: What about `testString('ABC', ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'])`?

Comment: @khelwood OP hasn't clarified... Same thoughts as Riccardo on this one.

Comment: this should return true